# Array inside a json object and object inside a json object using php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am trying to produce the following JSON from MySQL database using PHP. How do I go about doing it in PHP lets say using the explode function for getting the array into the JSON object. I don't know about getting the JSON object inside an object. I just need to separate PHP files to achieve the following.

```
<?php
include 'database.php';
$pdo = Database::connect();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users';
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($sql));
$array = array();
 while ($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
     array_push($array, $row);
 }
$json = json_encode($array);
echo $json;
Database::disconnect();?>
```

Array inside a JSON object:

```
[
{
  "firstName":"John", 
  "lastName":"Doe",
  "images": ['image1','image2','image3']
}, 
{
  "firstName":"Anna",   
  "lastName":"Smith",
  "images": ['image1','image2','image3']
},
{
 "firstName":"Peter", 
 "lastName":"Jones",
 "images": ['image1','image2','image3']
 }
]
```

JSON object inside an object:

```
[
{
  "firstName":"John", 
  "lastName":"Doe",
  "cover": {
            "cover_id": "0858699703",
            "source": "www.myimages.co.zw/images/photo",
            "offset_y": "0"
          }
}, 
{
  "firstName":"Anna",   
  "lastName":"Smith"
  "cover": {
            "cover_id": "0858699703",
            "source": "www.myimages.co.zw/images/photo",
            "offset_y": "0"
          }
},
{
 "firstName":"Peter", 
 "lastName":"Jones"
 "cover": {
            "cover_id": "0858699703",
            "source": "www.myimages.co.zw/images/photo",
            "offset_y": "0"
          }
 }
]
```

Comment: Just use `json_encode()` on your actual result set

Comment: Show the PHP code that is querying your database

Comment: <?php
    include 'database.php';
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM user';
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($sql));
    $array = array();
     while ($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
         array_push($array, $row);
     }
    $json = json_encode($array);
   echo $json;
    Database::disconnect();
    ?>

Comment: Check the update i have added the php

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
include 'database.php';
$pdo = Database::connect();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM test';
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($sql));
$array = array();
 while ($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

     $row_array['name'] = $row['name'];
     $row_array['surname'] = $row['surname'];
     $row_array['images'] =  explode(" ", $row['images']);

     array_push($array, $row_array);
 }
$json = json_encode($array);
echo $json;
Database::disconnect();
?>
```